# SAP B1 Choose from list employee but show name instead of code

Tags: sapb1

We had a choose from list on the service call for default technician which appears to have shifted since turning on multiple scheduling and upgrading to SAP B1 V10.

I need to get this technician field back onto the main form (via udf) where it can be used to show the default technician from the BP master data.

My issue is if i have a choose from list from the employee master data it is returning the code into the edittext field whereas i need the employee name but still have the choose from list and golden arrow to work.

Appreciate the assistance on this.

Comment: Hi Nick, did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

add a hidden edit Text to contain the code (or use a property / variable / or get from the dBDatasource )

if using a hidden box:
Trap the Choose from List Event and use the SelectedObjects to
place the name into visible edit text & code into the hidden one.

```
   Private Sub myNameBox_ChooseFromListAfter(sboObject As Object, pVal As SAPbouiCOM.SBOItemEventArg) Handles myNameBox.ChooseFromListAfter

      myCodeBox.Value =   pVal.SelectedObjects.GetValue("UserCode", 0)

    End Sub
```

otherwise just set the edit text cfl binding to Display the Name:

```
myNameBox.ChooseFromListAlias = "UserName"
```

to get the link button working simply Trap the Link button press before, set to bubble event false & manually open the desired form using the key from the hidden edit text / dbDatasource / Property

```
BubbleEvent = False
Application.SBO_Application.OpenForm(SAPbouiCOM.BoFormObjectEnum. formType , "", myCodeBox.Value)
```